# Python: Have an action happen within every single function of a python file

Tags: python, function, file

Sorry the title isn't very clear but it is kind of hard to explain. So I am wondering how you can have a certain action happen within every single function of a python file. I want a user to type 'paper' inside any function in the entire python file and I cannot figure out how to do it. Here is an example:

```
def a():
    raw_input()
    print "Test"

def b():
    raw_input()
    print "Test 2"
```

How can I have it setup so a user can type 'paper' in these two functions (realistically more than 30+) and then it would print the statement "you have a paper"

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: This doesn't make sense the way it is written. Can you elaborate more? Are you able to modify the source code?

Comment: Having a `raw_input` call in **each** function would require the user to input something into **each** function; not **any**.
What is the more general problem that you are trying to solve using this approach? (see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: may you are looking for [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Decorator)

Comment: Sorry it is not clear. I want a certain function to occur (let's say a function called 'paper()'). And to access it a user has to type "paper" into any raw_input inside any function. I do not want to manually input this is to occur on every single function and I was wondering if there is a way to call the 'paper' function anywhere in the file without adding it to every single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something you want to apply to every function, you should use a decorator.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this should demonstrate:

```
>>> def youhaveapaper(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        response = input('whatchu got?\n>>> ')
        if response == 'paper':
            print('you have a paper')
        return function(*args)
    import functools
    functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, function)
    return wrapper

>>> @youhaveapaper
def somefunction(x):
    """return the square of x"""
    return x**2

>>> y = somefunction(5)
whatchu got?
>>> paper
you have a paper
>>> y
25
```

As you can see, `somefunction` did not need to be changed, it just needed `@youhaveapaper` placed before the definition.

Comment: This is what I am looking for... Sadly I do not understand it. It is too advanced for me to grasp. So I will manually add it to each function. I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: @HenFish Decorators can be a little bit hard to understand if you've never seen them before, but I'd encourage you to find a tutorial on them before you give up.  They are a pretty powerful feature of Python!

Comment: I will definitely look into them when I get the chance. It is something I want to learn but I am trying to master the information I already know first. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the good comments and questions above. Do you mean this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                       

def paper(prompt):
    response = raw_input(prompt+' ')
    print('you have a {}'.format(response))

def a():
    paper('Test')

def b():
    paper('Test2')

a()
b()
```

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am looking for. I think the other answer got it but it is way above my experience and knowledge to understand so I will just manually add it to every function. Thank you so much for the help!